# Good Camera for High-Quality General Photography?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, camera-recommendation

I want to purchase a camera that I can use in a number of settings (out in nature, indoors, etc.) to take photographs of a high quality. I care about clarity and a good representation of color. I also want to be able to take simple point-and-click snapshots once I have configured the settings correctly. However, I will be taking mostly casual photos; I am an amateur.

I see a lot of people with Nikon or Canon cameras with big lenses and great customisability taking the sorts of pictures I want to take. Are there any recommendations for what Camera I should purchase? I'd like to stay under $300.

Comment: Take a look at [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) to see why this question got closed and downvoted so quickly.

Comment: You might also find some of our existing general questions about where to start when looking to buy a camera: [How do I choose between an SLR or an expensive P&S?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/16240/), and [Is an SLR camera a must when learning?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3160/), followed by [What should I look for when shopping for my first DSLR?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2876/) or [What features really matter in a point and shoot camera?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/17299/).

Comment: You can often find refurbished DSLR's with manufacturer warranties for $300 or under.  Shop around.

Answer (score 2):

That is a tight budget for quality photography. Whatever you will buy, take a look at the sensor size of the camera. Read [What's the relation between sensor size and image quality?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/26001/whats-the-relation-between-sensor-size-and-image-quality-noise-dynamic-range)

Then you'd want to put words "Camera reviews" in the search field in Google. Do not exclude the models that are outside your budget, because you might find your favourite camera inside your budget from a second-hand store. Also note that review sites often list the price of the camera for what it was when the camera model was just released, and prices may have dropped with time after the release. For just one example, [Olympus Pen E-PL1](http://www.dpreview.com/products/olympus/slrs/oly_epl1/overview) is a three year old model with decent image quality and you might find it in used camera sales well inside your budget.

Answer (score 0):

[The Panasonic Lumix DMC-ZS19](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00814CAS2) is a good all rounder beginner camera. It has many of the features of entry-level SLR's, is good in low light and has a good lens.